# Is it possible to change the response headers in IInternetProtocol?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I use the WebBrowser control in a WPF app.
I want that PDF files are always displayed in the browser.
Therefore i think the easiest way would be to change the response headers before IDownloadManager gets called.
When i could replace "Content-Disposition:attachment" with "Content-Disposition:inline" the download dialog should not appear.

I can view the response headers in IHttpNegotiate.OnResponse but i have found no way to change them.
Is it posible to change the response headers?

Comment: I suspect you would need to implement `IWinInetHttpInfo` on the handler, and return modified headers in `QueryInfo`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I make .NET web and desktop business applications but i have very less experience with c++, com and interfaces. What do you mean with "on the handler" ? I have patched the vtable of IInternetProtocol, IInternetProtocolSink and IHttpNegotiate but now i have no idea how to go on. I think the PassthruApp is from you, maybe thats a better approach. Do you have an example implementation that compile with current Visual Studio?